# В google maps api cгенерировать URL для https://www.google.com.ua/maps/

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть проект в котором используется **Google Maps API** для построения маршрута.

Сейчас задача у меня следующая: внутри web-приложения с помощью Google Maps API создать маршрут, после изменить маршрут передвигая маршрут на карте (которая находится в web-приложении) и после сгенерировать ссылку с помощью которой можно открыть гугл карты (https://www.google.com.ua/maps/) где должен отобразиться маршрут с учетом сдвига пользователем в приложении.

Другими словами: через Google Maps API сгенерировать ссылку, которая отобразит измененный маршрут в гугл картах

Смотрел документацию, анализировал запросы и ответы Google Maps API и гугл картах. Так и не нашел решение.

Хочу уточнить возможно ли реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: Разная функциональность. Нет.

Comment: @anatoly.sukhanov Что Вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Ответ на 98% дан по ссылке на сервисе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814427/in-google-maps-api-generate-a-google-maps-url/45846846#45846846

Comment: Не знал, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

**[HTML5 Geolocation](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)** указывает существующее/текущее положение пользователя. Вероятно вы можете применить для ваших карт следующий код javascript:

```js
<script>if (navigator.geolocation) { //Проверка поддержки браузером гео-локации
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {  //Получение
     var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    //текущего положения 
     var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 //пользователя
     var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); //Создает переменную для координат карты
     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
     var mapOptions = //Sets map options
     {
       zoom: 15,  //Установите требуемое вам приближение для карты(0-21)
       center: coords, 
       mapTypeControl: true, 
       navigationControlOptions:
       {
         style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL //размер контрольной панели карты
       },
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //опции для карты:ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID, TERRIAN
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
     var request = {
       origin: coords,
       destination: '65.791238, 21.657444',  //координаты объекта предлагаемого пользователю
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING //опции для карты:DRIVING, WALKING, BICYCLING, TRANSIT
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     }); 
     
   });
    
 }
 </script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Код ХТМЛ для такой карты:

```html
<main>
<header>
<h1>Название предлагаемого объекта</h1>
</header>
<div role=application>
<div>
<div id=map></div>
<div id="panel">
<div id="directions"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</main>
```

При изменении местоположения пользователя, он может обновлять карту, путём обновления браузера. В этом случае функция гео-локации карты будет показывать его новое текущее местоположение. Дополнительно: **[Документация Гугл о гео-локации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation)**.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ.
Но я думаю это не то что я ожидал